# Error 1046:Type not found or was not a compile-time constant:Listing2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to add a movieclip that is generated through a loop from SearchVectorTest class file, and put that into sresultnologin class file. Then i will make that movieclip clickable, and when clicked, goes to next class,display a new stage, pull the information from that specific stored in that movieclip, and pull the rest of the information from the database and display them.

I am having an error at the moment, Type not found. I can't seem to add the Movieclip(box) as a button. on this line var newListing:Listing2 = Bolder.getChildAt(0);

sresultnologin.as

```
    package com.clark

{
import com.clark.SearchVectorTest;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;




       public class sresultnologin extends MovieClip {

public var s1:Searchreult = new Searchreult ();

               public function sresultnologin(){
                  // init



            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);
         function onadded (event:Event):void{



            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);
         }

var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(new Vector.<searchVO1>);
                 addChild (s3);


            s1.SRhome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTol);
            s1.ARsearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGosearch);

 if( s3.listings.length > 0 )
        {
            // get the first listing in the listing array
            var newListing:Listing8 = s3.listings[0];
            newListing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscener);
        }
        else
        {



        }


           }

               // private methods
           private function gotoscener(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:Listingdetail = new Listingdetail ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);


       }


        private function fl_ClickToGoTol(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:Account = new Account ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);

        }

        private function fl_ClickToGosearch(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:searchVO1 = new searchVO1 ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);


       }

}
}
```

SearchVectorTest.as

```
   package  com.clark
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var listings:Vector.<Listing8>;

        public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1>) 
        {

for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) 
            {


                trace(test[j].nobed);
                trace(test[j].zip);
                trace(test[j].Location);
                trace(test[j].price);

        }

            var len:int = test ? test.length : 0;
         // create your vector for your listings with the len size
         listings = new Vector.<Listing8>(len, true);
            var currentY:int = 200;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing8 = new Listing8();

                Bolder.x=20;

                var bf:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

                bf3.width = 100;
                bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                bf.width = 100;
                bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf1.width = 100;
                bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.width = 100;
                bf1.y= bf.height+5;


                bf.text = test[k].nobed;
                bf1.text = test[k].zip;
                bf2.text = test[k].Location;
                bf3.text = test[k].price;

                bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.2
                Bolder.addChild(bf);
                Bolder.addChild(bf1);
                Bolder.addChild(bf2);
                Bolder.addChild(bf3);
                Bolder.properties = test[k].nobed;
                Bolder.properties = test[k].zip;

                    // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
                Bolder.y = currentY;


                addChild(Bolder);
                 Bolder.mouseChildren = false;    // ignore children mouseEvents
            Bolder.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
            Bolder.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
            Bolder.buttonMode = true; 
                 listings[k] = Bolder;
                currentY += Bolder.height + 10;
            }

        }


    }

}
```

SearchVO1

```
package com.clark
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;



       public class searchVO1 extends MovieClip {
        private var Arvariables:URLVariables;
        private var SrSend:URLRequest;
        private var SaLoader:URLLoader;
           public var nobed:String;
        public var zip:String;
        public var Location:String;
        public var price:String;
           public var callMethod:Function;

public var s1:searchpage = new searchpage ();

               public function searchVO1():void{

addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);                  // init
function onadded (event:Event):void{


            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);
             s1.account.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToaccount);
             s1.searchs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ValidateAndsearch);
            s1.Au.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToautomatch);
            s1.setting.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToss);
            s1.Shome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTohom);




            // Build the varSend variable
            SrSend = new URLRequest("http://localhost/search.php");
            SrSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
                   Arvariables = new URLVariables;
            SrSend.data = Arvariables;

            SaLoader = new URLLoader();
            SaLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            SaLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Asandler);


 // private methods

           function Asandler(event:Event):void{

 // retrieve data from php call
var resultString :String = event.target.data;
// parse result string as json object and cast it to array
var resultArray  :Array  = JSON.parse( resultString ) as Array;
// get the length of the result set
var len:int = resultArray.length;

// create vector of SearchVO
var searchVOs:Vector.<searchVO1> = new Vector.<searchVO1>();
// loop the result array
               var i:int;
for(i=0; i<len; i++ )
{
    searchVOs[i] = new searchVO1();   
    searchVOs[i].nobed = resultArray[i].nobed;
    searchVOs[i].zip = resultArray[i].zip;
    searchVOs[i].Location = resultArray[i].Location;
    searchVOs[i].price =  resultArray[i].price;
}

// call a function to create your boxes

// or maybe create your SearchVector class and pass it your search vector
var mySearchVector:SearchVectorTest = new SearchVectorTest(searchVOs);
addChild(mySearchVector);
       }   
   }
   }

    public function searchVOs( nobed:String, zip:String, location:String, price:String )
        {
            this.nobed      = nobed;
            this.zip        = zip;
            this.Location   = Location;
            this.price      = price;
        }
        public function ValidateAndsearch (event:MouseEvent):void {

        // validate fields

         Arvariables.nobed = s1.nobed.text;
        Arvariables.zip = s1.zip.text;
            Arvariables.Location = s1.Location.text;
            Arvariables.price = s1.price.text;
    SaLoader.load(SrSend);
            var s7:sresultnologin = new sresultnologin()    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);




        }
         // close else condition for error handling

         // close validate and send function





        private function fl_ClickToGoToautomatch(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var s7:Auto = new Auto ();  
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);
        }

        private function fl_ClickToGoToss(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //
        }
        private function fl_ClickToGoToaccount(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var s7:Account = new Account ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);
        }



        private function fl_ClickToGoTohom(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s7:homepage = new homepage ();  
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);

        }


       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to remove these lines:

```
public var Bolder:MovieClip;
public var Listing2:MovieClip;
```

and try to get your Listing2 object like this:

```
var newListing:Listing2 = s3.getChildAt(0);
```

but if you want to access your listings in the SearchVectorTest class it's better to keep a public reference of them like this (maybe in an array or a vector):

SearchVectortest class:

```
public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
{
    /** the array of listings **/
    public var listings:Vector.<Listing2>;

    public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1>) 
    {
         // put the array length in a variable -> if test = null make len = 0
         var len:int = test ? test.length : 0;
         // create your vector for your listings with the len size
         listings = new Vector.<Listing2>(len, true);
         // ...
         for( var k:int = 0; k < len; k++ ) 
         {
            var bolder:Listing2 = new Listing2();

            bolder.mouseChildren = false;    // ignore children mouseEvents
            bolder.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
            bolder.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
            bolder.buttonMode = true;        // this must be set to true to have hand cursor
            // add your linsting to the vector
            listings[k] = bolder;
            //...
         }
         // ...
    }
}
```

after that you could get your listing like this:

sresultnologin.as

```
public class sresultnologin extends MovieClip 
{
    public var s1           :Searchreult = new Searchreult ();

    //public var Bolder     :MovieClip;     // never used -> useless
    //public var Listing2   :MovieClip;     // never used -> useless

    public function sresultnologin()
    {
        // init
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);

        function onadded (event:Event):void
        {
            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);
        }

        var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(new Vector.<searchVO1>);
        addChild (s3);

        s1.SRhome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTol);
        s1.ARsearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGosearch);

        // verify if there are enties in the array
        if( s3.listings.length > 0 )
        {
            // get the first listing in the listing array
            var newListing:Listing2 = s3.listings[0];
            newListing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto);
        }
        else
        {
            // do something if there are no results
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

hope that helps ;)

Comment: when you get the listing in your sresultnologin.as it's better to check if listing contain 1 or more entries before to get the first. i go to edit it

Comment: I just gave it a go, if i use var newListing:Listing2 = s3.getChildAt(0); I have an error, type was not found. I used the second method, there is no error, but when i clicked on the box in the display page, it is not doing anything though.

Comment: try change your function name, goto is a function used by the compiler, change it to gotoResult or something else and add a trace in the function to see if the code go onto

Comment: the Listing2 object contain a background or just textFields ?

Comment: i just modified something in the SearchVectorTest class in the for loop try these modifications too

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out now, the Listing2 is a movieclip from the library, and when added on stage, it add the textfield inside it.

Comment: I just tried it, still can't click the Listing2(box), it isnt doing anything.

Comment: ok it's a movieClip from library but does it have some background ? or just nothing or just strokes ? because by default if there are no graphic data the mouseEvents don't work on nothing ;) so maybe add a background for testing

Comment: Ahh, its a movie clip that just a square green block. I will try to play around and see if it does anything different

Comment: Ah its not doing it still, its just a green/blue block(movieclip).

Comment: And the listings[i] = bolder; in SearchVectorTest it says Access of undefined Properties i, i changed that to k to remove the error. Not sure if that affected anything.

Comment: ha yes sorry it will be better i think ;)

Comment: I got adviced from another comment that the variable name is not the same as the name property on an object. So i should rename listings[k]? Or it should have worked already? Cos i changed that i to k and the button is still the same, wont click

Comment: I think, the boxes isn't being recognized so it is not doing anything. But not sure how to give the boxes name in the correct way.

Comment: there is no need to give a name as you keep a reference of it. Without seeing all the code and fla i don't know how to help you